# alternative to this rule calling rule on makefile

Tags: makefile

I have this makefile, it actually does the job, but I feel it's not pretty. My goal is simple, when someone call "make" for the first time, it will run both compile and staging, but consecutive call to make, it will call compile only. If user wants to run staging, user must call "make staging". Anyone has better idea?

```
all: compile

.PHONY: compile staging                                                         

compile:
    @echo "compile"
    @test -f ./.staging || make ./.staging

force_staging:
    @rm -f ./.staging

staging: force_staging compile
    @:

./.staging:
    @echo "staging"
    @touch $@
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [order only](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) dependencies:

```
all: compile

compile: | .staging
    echo $@
    touch $@

.staging: 
    echo $@
    touch $@

staging: .staging compile
```

Notice that if the user does `make staging`, then `.staging` will be a regular target and will rebuild if out of date.  If the user does `make all`, then `.staging` will only be rebuilt if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing for file existence I think you can add a dependency on `.staging`

```
all: compile

.PHONY: compile

compile: ./.staging
    @echo "compile"

force_staging:
    @rm -f ./.staging

staging: force_staging compile
    @:

./.staging:
    @echo "staging"
    @touch $@
```

Comment: sorry for not being clear, but compile must be executed first before staging

Comment: Then your approach looks the best for this task